# How do I find/list all files on filesystem with a certain SELinux "fcontext"

Tags: files, find, selinux

I'm having trouble finding information on what command, presumably from `setools`, I should use to find all the files on my filesystem that are labeled by SELinux with a certain file-context (`fcontext`).

---

At the moment, I can *manually* list the files along with their respective `fcontext`s from the file `/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files`, and then `grep` the specific `fcontext` I'd like to see.

```
[root@FedPadSSD files]# cat file_contexts |grep ifconfig_exec_t
/bin/ip --      system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0
/sbin/ip        --      system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0
/sbin/tc        --      system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0
/usr/bin/ip     --      system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0
/usr/sbin/ip    --      system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0
/usr/sbin/tc    --      system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0
/sbin/ethtool   --      system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0
/sbin/ifconfig  --      system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0
/sbin/iwconfig  --      system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0
/sbin/mii-tool  --      system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0
/usr/sbin/ethtool       --      system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0
/usr/sbin/ifconfig      --      system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0
/usr/sbin/iwconfig      --      system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0
/usr/sbin/mii-tool      --      system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0
/sbin/ipx_configure     --      system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0
/sbin/ipx_interface     --      system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0
/sbin/ipx_internal_net  --      system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0
/usr/sbin/ipx_configure --      system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0
/usr/sbin/ipx_interface --      system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0
/usr/sbin/ipx_internal_net      --      system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0
```

The problem with this is that, it seems, most of the time there's something wrong or missing/incomplete when you do it *manually* as it relates to the SELinux "database" (for lack of a better word).  **So, I wonder if something already exists in the `setools` package, or related packages, that accomplishes this without having to fuss around with the system-wide configuration files.**

Comment: You might need to do a `find / -type f -exec ls -lZ {} \;` and grep that output you the file context you're searching for. That file you're looking at is for persistent mappings. If someone did a `chcon` it won't reflect the file's current context, just what it'll revert to if you did a `restorecon`

Comment: GNU `ls` will list file contexts with `-Z`.

Comment: Thanks Joel for pointing out the issue with "persistence".  



mikeserv: yes, I'm aware of the `-Z` flag for `ls`; I could also do something like 

    `ls -alZR / |grep ifconfig_exec_t`

However, I was wondering if there's a more "official" way to do this with the proper tools dealing with SELinux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment on RHEL7.1--I'm not sure if this has always been there and I missed it--I can execute the following to get a list of all the filecontexts and just pipe the output to `grep`:

```
# semanage fcontext -l |grep ifconfig_exec_t
/bin/ip                                            regular file       system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0 
/sbin/ethtool                                      regular file       system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0 
/sbin/ifconfig                                     regular file       system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0 
/sbin/ip                                           regular file       system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0 
/sbin/ipx_configure                                regular file       system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0 
/sbin/ipx_interface                                regular file       system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0 
/sbin/ipx_internal_net                             regular file       system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0 
/sbin/iw                                           regular file       system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0 
/sbin/iwconfig                                     regular file       system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0 
/sbin/mii-tool                                     regular file       system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0 
/sbin/tc                                           regular file       system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0 
/usr/bin/ip                                        regular file       system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0 
/usr/sbin/ethtool                                  regular file       system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0 
/usr/sbin/ifconfig                                 regular file       system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0 
/usr/sbin/ip                                       regular file       system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0 
/usr/sbin/ipx_configure                            regular file       system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0 
/usr/sbin/ipx_interface                            regular file       system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0 
/usr/sbin/ipx_internal_net                         regular file       system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0 
/usr/sbin/iw                                       regular file       system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0 
/usr/sbin/iwconfig                                 regular file       system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0 
/usr/sbin/mii-tool                                 regular file       system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0 
/usr/sbin/tc                                       regular file       system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0
```

Answer (score 5):

`semanage fcontext -l | grep whatever_exec_t` is probably the best way to find labeling rules for specific context.

If you wish to search for current file contexts instead of labeling rules, you can use `ls -Z`, but SELinux-aware `find` supports `-context <glob>` test and `%Z` format specifier for `-printf`. Note that whole context string is matched against `<glob>`, so use wildcards when matching against type only. Example on my Centos 7.3:

```
#find / -xdev -type f -context '*ifconfig_exec_t*' -printf '%-50Z%p\n'
system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0              /usr/sbin/ip
unconfined_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0          /usr/sbin/ifconfig
system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0              /usr/sbin/ethtool
system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0              /usr/sbin/iw
unconfined_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0          /usr/sbin/mii-tool
system_u:object_r:ifconfig_exec_t:s0              /usr/sbin/tc
```

Comment: The only answer correctly answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

If your distro packages the `ifconfig_selinux` man page (Fedora has it in [selinux-policy-devel](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/selinux-policy-devel)), it'll tell you:

```
   The following file types are defined for ifconfig:

   ifconfig_exec_t

   - Set files with the ifconfig_exec_t type, if you want to transition an
   executable to the ifconfig_t domain.

   Paths:
        /bin/ip,    /sbin/ip,    /sbin/tc,    /usr/bin/ip,   /usr/sbin/ip,
        /usr/sbin/tc,   /sbin/ethtool,   /sbin/ifconfig,   /sbin/iwconfig,
        /sbin/mii-tool,       /usr/sbin/ethtool,       /usr/sbin/ifconfig,
        /usr/sbin/iwconfig,    /usr/sbin/mii-tool,    /sbin/ipx_configure,
        /sbin/ipx_interface, /sbin/ipx_internal_net, /usr/sbin/ipx_config‐
        ure, /usr/sbin/ipx_interface, /usr/sbin/ipx_internal_net
```

You can also use `sesearch -all -t ifconfig_exec_t` to see what transitions operate on files with a target of ifconfig_exec_t, which might help you find files with that context.

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I thought there might be a more descernable method with `sesearch`, but I've only been able to use it as you suggested so far.  It might be a nice feature to add to the **setools**

Answer (score 0):

The find command allows you to search by security context.

For example, let's search for all files of the type "unlabeled_t".

```
find / -type f -context *unlabeled_t*
```

The first part, "find / -type f," tells us to search all regular files on the system.

"-context *unlabeled_t*" filters to show us all files of type unlabeled_t.  We have to wildcard the beginning and end, because we don't care about the user/role at the beginning, or the MLS/MCS context at the end.